# Lektor : Error When Saving a Record in Admin : sqlite3.OperationalError OperationalError: database is locked

Tags: sqlite, lektor

I am randomly (my perception) getting the following error : "sqlite3.OperationalError OperationalError: database is locked" when I update a record in Lektor through the Admin interface. I have tried with several projects (quickstart, lektor-website), and I am still getting this "random" error. My config : Mac OS 10.11, latest version of Lektor (2.3), Python 2.7. Here is the traceback :

```
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2000, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1991, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1567, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1988, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1641, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1544, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1639, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1625, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lektor/admin/modules/serve.py", line 150, in serve_artifact
return serve_up_artifact(path)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site- packages/lektor/admin/modules/serve.py", line 129, in serve_up_artifact
artifact_name, filename = li.resolve_artifact('/' + path, pad)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lektor/admin/webui.py", line 60, in resolve_artifact
prog, _ = builder.build(source)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lektor/builder.py", line 1080, in build
self.update_source_info(prog, build_state)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lektor/builder.py", line 1047, in update_source_info
build_state.write_source_info(info)
File "/usr/local/lib/lektor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lektor/builder.py", line 240, in write_source_info
Open an interactive python shell in this frame''', [info.path, info.alt, lang, info.type, source, title])
```

Any advice on how this can be prevented ?

Thanks in advance !